# Which Ruby on Rails version should I upgrade to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, version, upgrade

I am using Ruby on Rails *3.2.9* and on the official blog it has been posted the following article: "[[SEC] [ANN] Rails 3.2.13, 3.1.12, and 2.3.18 have been released!](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/)".

My question is: Which Ruby on Rails version should I upgrade to?

---

*Note*: I ask this because in the linked blog post (and in related linked pages) there is a bit of confusion. I would be grateful if someone would tell me a little more about the upgrades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to upgrade to the latest release of the branch you are currently using, i.e. from *3.2.9* to *3.2.13*.

Answer (score 0):

rails current stable version(3.2.13)